# How to fetch new IP address under Ubuntu Server on VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation, ip-address, ubuntu-10.10

I have VMware Workstation 7 and Ubuntu Server 10.10 installed on it. When I copied my virtual hard drive to another PC it took same IP address.

Is it possible to somehow receive another IP address for other VM on other PC? I already tryed to do `dhclient -r` to release and `dhclient` ro get new, but then new IP address jumps from my network I guess. My IP is for example `192.168.119.xxx` and VM address is too `192.168.119.xxx`, but after steps I described before it changes to `192.168.85.xxx` and even after I restart VM it changes back to the way it was before.

Any suggestions?

**UPD:**
VMs do not have same MAC ( HWaddr ) address.

Comment: Is the MAC address the same on both copies?

Comment: No, `HWaddr` is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to `/etc/network/interfaces` and edited already set static ip. It was the problem. I guess, that when VM setup NAT it configured itself to use one specific static IP or maybe it is designed that way by default. Can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/networking/interfaces,

it should be set to :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If it is anything else change it to that (considering eth0 is the device you connect with to the internet)

Comment: If the dhcp server is intelligent enough it will offer the same IP as before as the NIC has the same MAC address.

Comment: Yes but if you read the comments you would notice the HWaddr is different mate.